# Extracting string value with multiple space in .sh

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I have file and content like

```
"SOME WORDS", "AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8234 78","SOME WORDS",
"AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8236 79"
```

How we can get`all 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xx'` matching pattern in .sh?

```
for fetchData in `grep -o 'AB*\s[0-9]*\s[0-9]*\s[0-9]*\s[0-9]*\s[0-9]*' FILE_NAME`
do
echo 'Data = '${fetchData}
done
```

Its printing

```
AB@@ 
9897 
...
..
```

But i want to print

```
'AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8234 78'
'AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8236 79'
```

Comment: As this is not a free coding service, we'd appreciate seeing some attempt first. Don't post is as a comment, image, table or link to off-site
service but use text and include it to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to read output line-by-line with a `for` loop -- [it's the wrong tool for the job](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Use a `while read` loop instead. See [BashFAQ #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: This is not a job for any shell language; what you have is (close enough to) a CSV file, so you should use a language that has a CSV parser available.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`. Using the `-o` flag.

```
grep -o 'AB@@.*7[89]' file.txt
```

If there are only numeric strings in between.

```
grep -o 'AB@@[0-9 ]*7[89]' file.txt
```

---

As per OP's comment. With the `-E` flag for [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

```
grep -Eo 'AB@@ [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{2}' file.txt
```

---

with the `-P` flag for [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions).

```
grep -Po 'AB@@ \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{2}' file.txt
```

By default `grep` is using [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)

Comment: No luck ,we have to fetch pattern for example 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xx'

Comment: With your given data, my solution works but If you have more sample data then please update your post otherwise there is an answer/post that did what you're looking for.

Comment: we have to fetch generic data in the form of 'AB@@ xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xx', more detail AB@@ is common only in string and rest xxxx could be numeric

Comment: grep -Eo 'AB@@ [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{2}' file.txt or grep -Po 'AB@@ \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{2}' file.txt giving me same result separately as  AB@@ 
9897 
...
.. in for loop , but i want whole matching result example AB@@ xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xx in loop.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ grep -o '".... .... .... .... .... .."' file.txt | tr -d \"
AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8234 78
AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8236 79
```

Comment: will it work in for fetchData in `grep -o 'AB*\s[0-9]*\s[0-9]*\s[0-9]*\s[0-9]*\s[0-9]*' FILE_NAME`
do
echo 'Data = '${fetchData}
done

Answer (score 0):

When I try your example, `grep` does not produce any output at all. The reason is that `\s` has not special meaning in a simple regexp.

You did not describe your string pattern exactly. Assuming that we can any sequence of characters which contains neither double quote, nor comma, as string to be returned, the following example works:

```
x='"SOME WORDS", "AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8234 78","SOME WORDS","AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8236 79"'
for fetchData in $(grep -o '[^",]*' <<<$x)
do
  if [[ $fetchData == *[^ ]* ]]
  then
    echo Found string: "$fetchData"
    # Process your data here
  else
    : # Ignored because only spaces
  fi
done
```

If you really need one day `\s` for representing a space, use the `-P` option.

Comment: we have file FILE_NAME.txt "SOME WORDS", "AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8234 78","SOME WORDS",
"AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8236 79"

Comment: Well, like in the example in my code, isn't it? I just defined the string literally for easier testing. You are free to use your file here instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, can you please try below and check if it works:

```
grep -Eo '[a-zA-Z0-9&._-@]{4}\s+[[:digit:]]{4}\s+[[:digit:]]{4}\s+[[:digit:]]{4}\s+[[:digit:]]{4}\s+[[:digit:]]{2}' file
```

Output:

```
AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8234 78
AB@@ 9897 7437 8788 8236 79
```